# Prove that $AB = 2DE$ in a right triangle if... (With no values, only properties)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

i was doing some geometry exercises and i found this one, pretty interesting, but i can't solve it, i've been trying for a couple of days. This is the exercise:

**Exercise.**  In the figure, $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ACD$ are  right triangles, also, $\angle BCA = 2 \angle ACD$. If $DE$ is the altitude (height) of triangle $\Delta ACD$, Prove that $AB = 2DE$
[image]

***What i've done:***

I drew an imaginary segment $OC$ what is the bisetion of $\angle ECB$, which makes $O$ to be a point that makes $AO = OB$. Thanks to that we know that $\angle OCB = \angle DCA$ , and, $\angle ADC = \angle ABC = \angle CED = 90°$, so, $\Delta ACD \sim \Delta OCB \sim \Delta DEC $, and i'm not sure what´s next.

I would appreciate any help, if there are properties that i don't know or something like that (And what are their names because they could be useful). 
How would you do it? is it possible without trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without trigonometric functions: The key to this is the circumcircle of ABCD (notice how both the circumcircles of ABC and ACD have their centres at the mid-point of AC and therefore coincide). Let the circumcentre of ABCD be Z. Use (or prove) the relationship of an angle at the centre and an angle on the periphery over the chord AD to see that $\angle AZD = 2 \angle ACD$. Then $\angle AZD = \angle BCA$ with $AC = 2 ZD$ because ZD is a radius of the circle. Therefor $EZD \sim ABC$ with scale factor 2 and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was tagged as trigonometry, too...  Let $\widehat{ACB} = \gamma$ so that $\widehat{DCA} = \gamma / 2$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
DE & = DC \sin \frac{\gamma}{2} \\
 & = AC \cos \frac{\gamma}{2} \sin \frac{\gamma}{2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} AC \sin \gamma \\
 & = \frac{AB}{2}
\end{align}
$$